# Include target file with wildcards in makefile all directive

Tags: wildcard, gnu-make

I thought this would be a no-brainer, but I can't seem to figure it out. Let's say I want to unzip all zip files in a directory and place the results in another directory. All files follow the pattern `region_*.zip`, where * is some id.

```
raster/region_%.tif: zip/region_%.zip
    unzip -d raster $<
```

My problem: How do I include this operation in my `all` directive?

```
# Does not work
all: raster_region_%.tif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make always works backward from the target you want to create, back to the source files (in this case zip files).

Make has to be told, somehow, what the target you want to create is.  It can't just intuit that out of thin air.

In this case, if you want to build a `.tif` file for each zip file you need to first get a list of all the zip files then convert them into the target files:

```
ZIPFILES := $(wildcard zip/region_*.zip)
TARGETS := $(patsubst zip/region_%.zip,raster/region_%.tif,$(ZIPFILES))

all: $(TARGETS)
```